# Pausar video cuando hago click en close en un modal

Tags: javascript, html, css

tengo un modal hecho con JavaScript usando el siguiente codigo:

```js
    document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement;


        if (target.hasAttribute('data-toggle') && target.getAttribute('data-toggle') == 'modal') {
            if (target.hasAttribute('data-target')) {
                var m_ID = target.getAttribute('data-target');
                document.getElementById(m_ID).classList.add('open');
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }

        // Close modal window with 'data-dismiss' attribute or when the backdrop is clicked
        if ((target.hasAttribute('data-dismiss') && target.getAttribute('data-dismiss') == 'modal') || target.classList.contains('modal')) {
            var modal = document.querySelector('[class="modal open"]');

            modal.classList.remove('open');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }, false);
```

```css
// Modal

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 9999;
}

 .flex {
    height: 100%;
  }

  .modal-window {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 7.5vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
  }

  .modal-window.small {
    width: 75%;
  }

  .modal-window.large {
    width: 75%;
  }

  .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  &.open {
    display: block;
  }

  .subheading {
    font-style: italic
  }

  .modal-close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 3;
  }

video {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }

.modal-init {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
 <div class="modal-init" data-target="simpleModal_2" data-toggle="modal">click me</div>

<!--MOdal-->
<div id="simpleModal_2" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-close" data-dismiss="modal">X</div>
    <div class="flex full-center">
        <div class="modal-window flex full-center">
            <video class="video-modal video" controls="" controlslist="nodownload"
                   poster="https://cyberfitnesspro.de/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/titelbild_cyberfitnesspro_imagefilm_.jpg">
                <source src="https://cdn-cyberconcept.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/210504_CFP_Imagevideo_vs3_mck.mp4"
                        type="video/mp4">
                <source src="https://cdn-cyberconcept.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/210504_CFP_Imagevideo_vs3_mck.mp4"
                        type="video/ogg">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
            <p class="text">Video 2 Tom</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

El problema es que necesito implementar un fagmento de codigo para que en el momento que hago close al modal, se pare el video que esta dentro y no doy con la solucion a esto
Alguien me podria ayudar? Gracias por adelantado

P.D: NO se por que el codigo no funciona aqui, en mi web funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

intenta usando esto, es lo que yo uso para mis modales con video, pero aclaro que uso modales de bootstrap

```
$("#simpleModal_2").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $(".modal-window").find('video').remove();
    })
}
```

Espero ayudarte con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas, Suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Primero es necesario tener la referencia al directa al `video` de esta manera:

```
let video = document.getElementById('video');
```

Como esto devuelve una referencia por su id (lo cual es mejor), el `video` debe tener una **id**:

```
<Video id="video" controls></video>
```

Luego definidas estás dos cosas, ya sólo queda dar `play` o `pause` al `video`:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;


    if (target.hasAttribute('data-toggle') && target.getAttribute('data-toggle') == 'modal') {
        if (target.hasAttribute('data-target')) {
            var m_ID = target.getAttribute('data-target');
            document.getElementById(m_ID).classList.add('open');
            e.preventDefault();
            video.play(); // play vídeo
        }
    }

    // Close modal window with 'data-dismiss' attribute or when the backdrop is clicked
    if ((target.hasAttribute('data-dismiss') && target.getAttribute('data-dismiss') == 'modal') || target.classList.contains('modal')) {
        var modal = document.querySelector('[class="modal open"]');

        modal.classList.remove('open');
        e.preventDefault();
        video.pause(); // pausa el vídeo
        // video.currentTime = 0; // opcional 
    }
}, false);
```

Esto debería funcionar en **JavaScript** junto con el modal. En caso de que nó sea así, por alguna u otra razón (usando jQuery), agrega lo siguiente:

```
video[0].pause();
```

Comment: Yo no probé el código. Pero si el modal abre y cierra correctamente, ```play()``` y ```pause()``` funcionará correctamente

Comment: Pero en la web van a ver mas videos  con mas modales. Tengo que trabajar con id's que vaya modificandose

Comment: Buena siesta. No es recomendable tener varios modales en una página y varios vídeos. Esto es mucho código HTML5 y relentiza la carga de la página por haber tantos vídeos. **Es mejor un solo modal y un solo vídeo** y cargar todos los vídeos en un solo ```src=""``` del vídeo y los demás en un mismo modal.